# css border radius only displaying *after* jquery slideDown

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown

Very new to jquery here so go easy on me ;-)

I'm experimenting with a simple drop down menu.

It seems to be working fine but with one small problem.

When I hover over a level_1 menu element, the slide Down kicks in but the border radius settings defined in css only seem to kick in *after* the level_2 elements have slid down.

The result is, as the  level_2 div slides down the edges are square. When the slide Down is complete the edges round off.

I feel this may have something to do with padding. I've tried setting padding on level_2 to 0 - the problem persists with the one on the left. In addition it knocks the styling all over the place although there's probably a work around there.

I've included my full code below. Does anyone know what's going on here? Is this something very simple or is it going to require a redo from start? ;-)

Thanks in advance
Stef

*** The CSS ***

```
<style>
.level_1 {
border-radius:15px;
border: 1px solid black;

margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
padding: 5px 10px;

width: 150px;
height: 20px;

font-family: Century Gothic;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 900;
color: #ffffff;

text-align: center;
vertical-align: text-bottom;

display: block;
list-style: none;
float: left;
z-index: 10;

background-color: #d800ff;
}

.level_2 {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
left: -11px;

border: 1px solid black;
border-radius:15px;
margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
padding: 0;

width: 150px;

background-color: #b003cf;

font-family: Century Gothic;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 900;
color: #ffffff;

text-align: center;
vertical-align: text-bottom;

list-style: none;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

*** The HTML ***
<nav class="container">
<div class="level_1">Item 1
<div>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 1</a>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 2</a>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 3</a>
</div>      
</div>

<div class="level_1">Item 2
<div>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 1</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="level_1">Item 3
<div>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 1</a>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 2</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="level_1">Item 4
<div>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 1</a>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 2</a>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 3</a>
<a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 4</a>
</div>
</nav>

***The Jquery***
$('.level_1').hover(
function(){
$(this).children().stop().slideDown("slow");
},
function(){
jQuery.dequeue( this );
$(this).children().stop().slideUp("slow");
}
);

$('a').hover(
function(){
$(this).css("background-color","#9302ad");
},
function(){
$(this).css("background-color","#b003cf");
}
);
$('.level_1').children().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue actually lies with your padding and also relative positioning of the submenu. Removing `left: -11px;` and adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `a` tags fixes it somewhat (in Chrome at least)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/93z5g/2/)

---

Could I make a suggestion? I personally find this method of structuring these types of menus much more readable (and more predictable)...

HTML:

```
<nav class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="level_2" href="#">Level 2 - Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.container ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

.container ul li a {
    display: block;
}

.container ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
```

Which also simplifies your JQuery a bit:

```
$('.container ul > li').mouseenter(function() {
   $('ul',this).stop().slideDown("slow");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('ul',this).stop().slideUp("slow");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bpm8C/2/)

Comment: Much appreciated - thank you. I'm going to have a play around with that and incorporate it. I think my newbieness is very apparent re. the html structure as it pertains to the menu etc. Thanks again ;-)